# php is not echoing text while executing

Tags: php

I have a php script that gets called from a upload form, the script puts entries into a database. I would like to see the results on my browser as the script is running. I am using the code below, but the output shows up after the whole script has finished executing. My server is Apache2 running on Ubuntu. I thought by using `ob_start();` I can see the progress while the script is executing. Am I doing something wrong in my code?

```
 ob_start();
 foreach ($csvAsArray as $value)
 {
  $username = $value[0];
  $password = $value[1];
  $db->insert($username, $password, $machine);
  echo $username . " Inserted into database! <br />";
  ob_flush();
 }
 echo('done.');
 ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: In obstart u need a variable which get ob content

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

Comment: On the contrary, the [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) is used to capture the output instead of sending it to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ob_start :

```
<?php

 for($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
 {
  echo $i;
  flush();
  ob_flush();
  sleep(1);
 }
 echo 'done.';
 ob_end_flush();

 ?>
```

From Comment:

> php flush : Flushes the system write buffers of PHP and whatever
>   backend PHP is using (CGI, a web server, etc). This attempts to push
>   current output all the way to the browser with a few caveats. flush()
>   may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server
>   and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser. It
>   also doesn't affect PHP's userspace output buffering mechanism. This
>   means you will have to call both ob_flush() and flush() to flush the
>   ob output buffers if you are using those.

Comment: Please provide explanation to the code, for other users that will need help with similar issues in future

Comment: [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) flush :  Flushes the system write buffers of PHP and whatever backend PHP is using (CGI, a web server, etc). This attempts to push current output all the way to the browser with a few caveats.

flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser. It also doesn't affect PHP's userspace output buffering mechanism. This means you will have to call both ob_flush() and flush() to flush the ob output buffers if you are using those.

Comment: @christophe It'd be more helpful if you'd explain your code **inside** your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try with this use ob_get_contents() to get data

```
   ob_start();
   foreach ($csvAsArray as $value)
   {
     $username = $value[0];
     $password = $value[1];
     $db->insert($username, $password, $machine);
     echo $username . " Inserted into database! <br />";

 }
  $data = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  var_dump($data);
```